# Select, count, and Group the value in a table that has been joined

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server, and I have two tables: `product_assembly` and `product_testing` in the production database

`product_assembly` table:

| serial_number | batch |
| --- | --- |
| xx11 | 1 |
| xx12 | 1 |
| xx13 | 2 |
| xx14 | 2 |
| xx15 | 1 |
| xx16 | 3 |
| xx17 | 3 |
| xx18 | 3 |
| xx19 | 2 |

Table `product_testing`:

| serial_number | batch |
| --- | --- |
| xx11 | Passed |
| xx12 | Passed |
| xx13 | Passed |
| xx14 | Failed |
| xx15 | Passed |
| xx16 | Passed |
| xx17 | Failed |
| xx18 | Passed |
| xx19 | Passed |

How can I get a table like this.

I tried using count, join, and nested SELECT but it doesn't work.

Thank you

| Batch | Passed | Failed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: Please - leave the properly formatted text tables - do **NOT** post your tables as screenshots!

Comment: oke, im sorry . .

Answer (score 1):

We can use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    pa.batch,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pt.batch = 'Passed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Passed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN pt.batch = 'Failed' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Failed
FROM product_assembly pa
LEFT JOIN product_testing pt
    ON pt.serial_number = pa.serial_number
GROUP BY
    pa.batch;
```

Comment: its working fine.. grtt thanks..